# Find and delete all but N largest files in 100s of directories

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have 100s of sibling directories on a BSD/Unix system, each with a collection of files in it.  I'd like to delete all but the N largest files in each directory. (N is 5 for me.)

Assuming that I can use some 'find' magic for this, but not quite sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running this command, I think you'll like it

`find /path/to/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -s | sort -rn | awk 'NR>5 {print $NF}' | xargs rm -f`

This will print all files underneath the `/path/to/dir` directory, compute the size of each file, sort by size, extract out the names of all (except the top 5) files, and pass that to `rm`.

To perform this on each directory individually, you're better off wrapping it in a script, like

```
#!/bin/bash

for DIR in `find /path -maxdepth 1 -type d`
do
    find ${DIR} -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -s | sort -rn | awk 'NR>5 {print $NF}' | xargs rm -f
done
```

Where `/path` is the parent directory that contains all of your sibling directories. This will accomplish the same thing that @TomNewton describes by individually executing the workflow on each sibling directory.

Comment: Getting close.  It looks like this treats the whole lot as one sort.  It ends up deleting everything but the 5 biggest files across all directories.  I need the five biggest files in *each* directory.

Comment: Seems like you might have to wrap this in a bash "for" loop to do each of your sibling directories. Suggest replacing "rm -f" with "echo" until you're 100% happy too!

Seems from your comment, which I missed, you are putting /path/to/dir as your top dir. Scott meant that to be each sibling, so that line needs to be executed once per sibling, eg:

for i in master/* do find $i -type f.... ; done

Comment: Could replace `awk ...` by `tail -n +6`.

Comment: @jfgagne Since the `du` is of the form "size filename" (needed for sorting) we still need the awk to strip out the size column. Otherwise you would need to replace it with a combination of tail and cut.

Comment: @Scott: true, I did not see the cut involved in awk .  Using cut and tail makes the solution easier to understand, don't you think ?

Comment: @Scott: about `find /path -maxdepth 1 -type d`, it also return `/path`.  To avoid that, use `find /path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`.

Comment: Finally, if you have lots of `DIR`in `/path`, the construct `find /path -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read DIR; do ... done` or `while read DIR; do ... done < <(find /path -maxdepth 1 -type d)` might be safer.  The 2nd let you set variables in the while that can be accessed out of the loop